Python polar contour plot problems -
I am trying to solve it and encountering numerous problems with contour plot in Python. I have a relatively large set of data as XYZ (20000 point), with a polar component (degrees), and they are not evenly spaced -0 actual measurement data. I need to create a contour polar plot. I Have tried pet.contour with no success. Looked thoroughly thousands of posts, some of them helpful, some with incomplete information.
I was able to partially be successful with tricontourf, but does not look great. An example of data is here.
data.xlsx
Here is the code and output for that:
df = df.read_excel('......xlsx', ...)

data_arr = df.to_numpy()

direction= np.radians(data_arr[:,1])
values = data_arr[:,0]
zeniths = data_arr[:,2]


r, theta = np.meshgrid(zeniths,direction)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection='polar'))    

#/limits for the colorscale
lmin=min(data_arr[:,0])
lmax=max(data_arr[:,0])

colormap = plt.get_cmap('rainbow')
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(lmin, lmax)

ax.set_theta_zero_location("N")
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)

ax.tricontourf(direction,zeniths,values,30, cmap=colormap)

plt.show()

I get this graph:

Would prefer a better interpolation.
One example what I tried is
import pandas as df
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import * 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import interpolate

df = df.read_excel('...xlsx', )
data_arr = df.to_numpy()

direction= np.radians(data_arr[:,1])
values = data_arr[:,0]
zeniths = data_arr[:,2]

def grid(direction, zeniths, values, resX=100, resY=100):
  xi = np.linspace(min(direction), max(direction), resX)
  yi = np.linspace(min(zeniths), max(zeniths), resY)
  Z = interpolate.griddata(direction, zeniths, values, xi, yi, method='cubic')
  X, Y = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)
  return X, Y, Z
X, Y, Z = grid(direction, zeniths, values)
contour = plt.contourf(X,Y,Z)

It gives the error:
Exception has occurred: TypeError
griddata() got multiple values for argument 'method'
File “…Contour polarPlot 2", line 20, in 
grid=Z = interpolate.griddata(direction, zeniths, values, xi, yi, method='cubic')
   
  File "/ Contour polarPlot 2", line 23, in
<module> X, Y, Z = grid(direction, zeniths, values)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: griddata() got multiple values for argument 'method'

Tried different combination of contourf, contour etc., Always get some sort of an error. Possible it is associated with wrong array format, but not sure how to fix it

too much code, and missing example data, please reduce to this:
minimal reproducible example

fixed it as per your advise

That Box link is behind a credential wall. Convert the data to CSV and embed them directly in the question.

OK, posted it on goggle drive as public
